# How to repair a bad row selection from dataTable jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, datatables

I have two jquery dataTables in my php file. First table is loaded in the main file php from mysql database. The second table is loaded with ajax to the same php file but the content depend of row clicked on the first dataTable.

I have a problem, when I click the row of the first dataTable it loads the second table correctly. However when I click a row in the second dataTable not get some value, like not found the row. It show undefined value...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  **//I create dataTable 1**
  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    "language": {
      "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/9dcbecd42ad/i18n/Spanish.json"
    }, "dom": '<"toolbar">frtip'
  });
  **//I create dataTable 2**
  var table2 = $('#example2').DataTable({
    "language": {
      "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/9dcbecd42ad/i18n/Spanish.json"
    }, "dom": '<"toolbar">frtip'
  });

    **//I load dataTable 1**
  $('#example tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
    if ( $(this).hasClass('selected') ) {
      $(this).removeClass('selected');
    }else{
      table.$('tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
      $(this).addClass('selected');

      var getted = table.row('.selected').data();
      $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        data: 'usuario=' + getted,
        url: 'loadF1.php',
        success: function(msg) {
          $('#example2 tbody').html(msg);  //Here set content into div2
        }
      });

      **//I load dataTable 2**
     $('#example2 tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
       if ( $(this).hasClass('selected') ) {
         $(this).removeClass('selected');
       }else{
         table2.$('tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
         $(this).addClass('selected');
         var getted2 = table2.row('.selected').data();
         $.ajax({
           type:'POST',
           data: 'usuario=' + getted2,
           url: 'loadF2.php',
           success: function(msg) {
             $('#example3 tbody').html(msg);  //Here set content into div3
           }
         });
```

What am I doing wrong, why when I select the second table it's not getting get the row selected?

Thanks!

Comment: you cant change the content inside a datatables using html manipulation... you ve to use datatables methods

Comment: ah this could be the error, but.. what is the method to refresh content table? If I use .draw(msg) don't do anything.

Comment: [clear()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/clear()) for empty the table then [add()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row.add()) to add new data.... check the datatables api [here](https://datatables.net/reference/api/)

Comment: Thanks! Then.. I have a new problem, because I return an echo"" with "<tr > \n <td> ..." code to add this with html into tbody. And for this need code return with json¿?

Comment: there is a method to add data using a json.... or you need to parse your php response